SELECT con una condición con referencia a otra tabla en MySQL
Quisiera hacer un select con una condición con referencia a otra tabla.
Select * from tabla1 where id != tabla2.id1 and id != tabla2.id2


Hay alguna relación entre ambas tablas para que puedas hacer un JOIN?

La verdad, no se que impide responder esta pregunta de manera rápida, o enviar a una publicación antigua, etc.
La manera de hacerlo, es un un JOIN, para unir ambas tablas.
SELECT t1.* --seleccion de datos
FROM tabla1 t1 --tabla principal
LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 --tabla secundaria
ON t1.id = t2.id1 OR t1.id = t2.id2 --condicion del join
WHERE t2.id1 IS NULL; --condicion de filtro

